# What lawsuits have been filed against Wright State University?

Tags: graduate-school, academic-life, legal-issues

What lawsuits have been filed against Wright State University?

This school was operating as an unaccredited institution for years while engaging in research and academic fraud, as well as various discriminatory employment practices. I want to understand any legal precedents or issues with this institution.